# Need help Converting a jQuery event to a Drupal Behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7

I have a Drupal 7 web site that is using jQuery animations to fadeIn div tags.  I need an event to capture a fadeIn when it is completed.  I have found a sample jQuery example that does what I need it to, but I have not been able to successfully convert it to a Drupal 7 behavior and I'm not quite sure what I might be missing.

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/tkoscielski/dpz4rrxb/1/)

Below is my Drupal JS file, `fadeInEvent.js`.

```
Drupal.behaviors.fadeInEvent= {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

        var _old = jQuery.fn.fadeIn;

        jQuery.fn.fadeIn = function() {
            var self = this;
            _old.apply(this.arguments).promise().done(function(){
                self.trigger('fadeIn');
            });
        };

        jQuery('.tab-pane').bind('fadeIn', function() {
             alert('fadeIn Done.');
        });

    }
};
```

In the above JS code, I never get my alert that the fadeIn has finished on the item I have selected.

Answer (score 1):

Firs of all, while using jQuery in `noconflict` mode, you may use a closure to access it by `$`

```
(function($) {
    // jQuery code using $ object.
}(jQuery));
```

Regarding the `.fadeIn()`, consider my snippet:

```js
/**
 * $.fn.fadeInNew plugin for triggering 'fadeInDone', when .fadeIn is done.
 *
 * @param speed
 * @param easing
 * @param callback
 * @returns {$.fn}
 */
$.fn.fadeInNew = function(speed, easing, callback) {

  var self = this;

  self.animate({
    opacity: "show"
  }, speed, easing, function() {
    self.trigger('fadeInDone');

    if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
      callback.apply(self);
    }
  });

  return self;
}

$('.tab-pane').on('fadeInDone', function() {
  alert('Alarm!');
});

$('.button').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.tab-pane').fadeInNew();
});
```

```css
.tab-pane {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-pane">Have a good day!</div>
<button class="button">Show something!</button>
```

Since I don't really like the idea of overriding the native methods of any libraries, I have made a plugin `.fadeInNew()`, which will trigger custom `fadeInDone` event on the element. The code behind animation is almoast the same as in native implementation [see the source here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/b3b2d6c3dd51fbdc69e1942e9af75cc99a1834c2/src/effects.js#L600).

Also, you don't need to use `Drupal.behaviors` to define something like that. You should use `attach` only for things that are being loaded with Drupal's ajax framework, see `includes/ajax.php`